# Creating objects dynamically c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, linked-list

Well, i've read many different posts about this topic, but none could solve my question.

How can i dynamically create objects, and store them in a linked list.

i've this code that an object saves a number, and then it has a pointer that points to the next number, for representation only. 
For example: 17

One->next = seven. Boths are objects of the same class.

```
    class Class{
private:
    int value;
    Class *pNext; //Points to the next object in the linked list.
public:
    Class(){value = 0;  }
    ~Class(){;}

    void setV(int x){ value = x;}
    int getV(){return value;}

    //void setP(Class *p){ pNext = p;} ?? Is this right?
 };

int main(){
Class *pFirst; //pointer to first element
Class *pLast;  //pointer to last element
Class *pCurrent; //pointer to current element

for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++){
    pCurrent = new Class;
    pCurrent->setV(i);
    //pCurrent->setP(NULL);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++){
    cout << pCurrent->getV() << " ";
}

return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: *and destroys* - Nope, `new`ed objects stored in pointers do not get automagically destroyed, which is why that isn't preferred.

Comment: As far as I can see your loop never destroys objects it created. It does not link them properly, either, so they do not make a list. Additionaly the class constructor fails to initialize all object members, specifically leaving a `pNext` pointer uninitialized, so traversing a 'list' will almost certainly end with a crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the list permanent, you first have to declare your head node and then for each iteration in your for loop, add on to that list.

```
int main() 
{

    Class *pFirst; //pointer to first element
    pFirst->setV(0);
    Class *pLast;  //pointer to last element
    Class *pCurrent; //pointer to current element
    pFirst->pNext = pCurrent; // To keep track of the list via head


    for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++) 
    {
        pCurrent = new Class;
        pCurrent->setV(i);
        pCurrent->pNext = NULL;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++)
    {
        cout << pCurrent->getV() << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```